# Expo / Firestore, can't upload image using uploadBytesResumable

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, firebase-storage

I have this Expo project where I have to upload a profile image. Updating everything works fine but when I want to upload the image, to Firebase Storage, sometimes it uploads just fine but sometimes the app crashes, no error message, no nothing. It happens in both, the simulators and devices (iOS and Android), between 18% to 80% of completion.

Here's the upload function and the import statement as well:

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const uploadImage = async (theImage) => {

        const response = await fetch(theImage);
        const file = await response.blob();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${signedUser.uid}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

        // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
            case 'paused':
                console.log('Upload is paused');
                break;
            case 'running':
                console.log('Upload is running');
                break;
            }
        }, 
        (error) => {
            console.log("Error: ", error.message)
        }, 
        () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                /*console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                navigation.navigate({
                    name: 'Perfil',
                    params: { changed: true },
                    merge: true,
                  });*/
                navigation.goBack();
            });
        }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can patch your `@firebase/storage` scope package to upload the image as expected, without crashing!

Firstly, navigate to `node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js`, and then comment out the if-statement to prevent it from sometimes clearing the timeout (which seems to be causing the crash, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5848#issuecomment-1302630181).

```
function clearGlobalTimeout() {
    // if (globalTimeoutId) {
    //     clearTimeout(globalTimeoutId);
    // }
}
```

Now that you've made changes to a node_module, you can make these changes sticky by using yarn's Patch Package!

Changes to the `@firebase/storage` node_module will not be sticky unless a patch file is created — and you must tell your app to use that patch file after time the every node_modules are freshly installed. These changes can even be deployed through EAS build in production by adding a `postinstall` script to the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

To get started with patching your own `@firebase/storage`, use [yarn's Patch Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) module.